# Change video Release Date in iTunes

Tags: itunes, macos, video-editing

Until now, I could change Release Date on videos without problem. But, from now, If the video hasn't Release Date field, when I tried to edit, it always appears `05/06/05` on that field and I could not edit it.

Is this a general issue?

Any way to update that field?

**iTunes 12.0.1.26**

Comment: give us more details like iTunes version?

Comment: thanks, so what do you think why is there no Release date to start with?

Comment: Don't know, but it's irrelevant. Files with a correct release data has not accepted changes on this field.

Comment: ok, since it is irrelevant maybe someone else can help you. good luck

Comment: @Buscar웃 please don't get me wrong. I meant, the fact that files have or haven't release date is the irrelevant thing, because in both cases the release date can't be changed. And I really don't know why those files hasn't release date, mostly because were downloaded from internet I suppose.